# Replace 2 strings of a textbox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have 1 textbox in this form:

"Customer received XXX but order XXXX. Sent to queue for further research."

I have made textboxes where they can put the "XXX" value and "XXXX" value but it is not working, like it only shows the default text (which I mentioned above). Moreover, when I use the `instr` function, it only changes the "XXX" value, not the "XXXX".

So here's what I have:

```
If instr(me.textbox1.text, "XXX") Then
me.textbox1.text = Replace(TextBox1.text, "XXX", me.TextBox2.text)
```

Apparently, this works if I only want to have only 1 search condition. But it seems that `instr` is not working with multiple if conditions since it is not like `boolean`. Do you have any workaround in this kind of situation?

Comment: `instr(me.textbox1.text, "XXX")>0` will return a boolean.  Instr returns the relative location of the search string in the target string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `If` at all. The `Replace()` method will do nothing if the search string is not found in the text. So simply call the `Replace()` for each of your search strings, one after another:

```
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "XXX", TextBox2.Text)
TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "XXXX", TextBox3.Text)
```

Comment: OMG this one works! I though this Find and Replace can only be done thru instr function. THANK YOU SOOO MUCCHH